# Is there a way for SDL2 to render to a GPIO screen raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, sdl-2, gpio

I'm trying to write a graphical program using SDL2 to output to a 2.3 inch screen connected through the GPIO pins on the raspberry pi.  I can't seem to get the monitor to be recognized by SDL.

I read somewhere that these gpio monitors aren't recognized as regular monitors.  Is this true?  And is there any way to get SDL to use it?

I appreciate any help anyone has!

My code if anyone is interested:

```
struct {
    SDL_Rect bounds;
    SDL_Window* window;
} window_data;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    int num_displays = SDL_GetNumVideoDisplays();
    printf("\n\n\t%s\n\n", num_displays);

    struct window_data screens[num_displays];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_displays; i++) {
        SDL_GetDisplayBounds(i, &(screens[i].bounds));
        screens[i].window =
            SDL_CreateWindow("Display " + i, screens[i].bounds.x,
            screens[i].bounds.y, screens[i].bounds.w,
            screens[i].bounds.h, SDL_WINOW_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

Edit:  It looks like the little display is seen as a framebuffer device in /dev/fb1. I can write to it though static comes out.  (fb0 being my HDMI display).  Is my code correct for cycling through the framebuffer devices?  When I use this method, it doesn't seem to detect the HDMI display either.

Edit2: Would something like DirectFB assist me here for providing an interface for the framebuffer devices?  Am I on the right track with that idea?

Edit: DirectFB is in alpha on the pi and is not recommended I learned.  My goal is to draw image files and a bit of text on the screen and be able to choose the image's rotation.  At this point I'm open to any way I can realistically achieve this.